# Extending Array of tuples of equatables to find the first tuple matching

Tags: swift

This might be a noob question, however I can't seem to be able to write something like this

```
extension Array where Element == (E1, E2), E1: Equatable, E2: Equatable {
    func contains(_ tuple: (E1, E2)) -> Bool {
        return contains { $0.0 == tuple.0 && $0.1 == tuple.1 }
    }
}
```

What I want is to extend an array of tuples made of `Equatable` values so that I can find out if a certain tuple belongs to that array or not.

I can write a free function like this

```
func inArray<E1: Equatable, E2: Equatable>(_ tuple: (E1, E2), _ array: [(E1, E2)]) -> Bool {
    return array.contains { t in t.0 == tuple.0 && t.1 == tuple.1 }
}
```

, but I'd like, if possible, to attach this function to `Array`.

Also note that I am kinda stuck to tuples, so can't use other constructs like `Equatable` structs/enums/classes to model this.

Comment: I think that whatever you are storing in an array of tuples should better be stored in an array of <insert custom struct here>.

Comment: @Sweeper yes I know, but the context I need this requires tuples...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47841948/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by constraining the method instead of the 
extension:

```
extension Array  {
    func contains<E1, E2>(_ tuple: (E1, E2)) -> Bool where E1: Equatable, E2: Equatable, Element == (E1, E2) {
        return contains { $0.0 == tuple.0 && $0.1 == tuple.1 }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let a = [(1, "a"), (2, "b")]
print(a.contains((1, "a")))
```

Comment: @Cristik No. `E1` and `E2` are both constrained, which means `Element` is also constrained. I didn't know that you can constrain the surrounding class' generic parameters in a generic method until now!

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Array  {
    func contains<T: Equatable, U: Equatable>(_ tuple: Element) -> Bool where Element == (T, U) {
        return contains{tuple.0 == $0.0 && tuple.1 == $0.1}
    }
}
```